# TypeError: UserProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: django, django-models

`Error`

```
   TypeError at /spotify/authorize/
   UserProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Aim is to create a `UserProfile` as soon as a `user` is created

`models.py`

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
   liked_songs = models.ForeignKey("Song", on_delete= models.CASCADE, default=None)
class Meta:
    db_table = "UserProfile"

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
  if kwargs["created"]:
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs["instance"])

 post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

class Album(models.Model):
    Album_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)  

class Meta:
    db_table= "Album"

class Song(models.Model):
  track_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  artiste_name= models.CharField(
   max_length=200,  default=None  
   )
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete= models.CASCADE) 

class Meta:
    db_table="Song"

def __str__(self):
    return self.track_name
```

`views` for `authorize/`(part of it)

```
user , created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=spotify_user['uri'], 
first_name=spotify_user["display_name"])
template_name = "try.html"
return render(request, template_name)
```

Comment: There is a trailing comma at the `user = ...`, line, thus Django does not see this as a field. You should remove the trailing comma and make migrations to add the `user` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for this. I get another error; `NOT NULL constraint failed: UserProfile.liked_songs_id` when i user `authorize/` route, will update to include `views` for that route.

Comment: of course, when you create a `UserProfile`, you do not specify a `liked_song`, and since it has no `null=True`, you can not use `None` as default.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for this information...